# Fractional factorial design with mixed categorical and numerical variables analysis for more than two levels

Tags: categorical-data, experiment-design, categorical-encoding, mixed-type-data, fractional-factorial

I have an experiment setup that consists of multiple continuous and multiple categorical variables. Right now, I am just using two levels for the categorical variables, allowing me to encode them as -1 and 1, and thereby, in terms, allowing me to do a simple linear-regression analysis for the entire/fractional model (currently up to three-factor interactions, and using a resolution V design).

I am planning a similar experiment, where I have both numerical and categorical variables too, yet this time the categorical variables have more than two levels. The options I have seen to encode these categorical variables are:

1. Encoding every level as an on/off variable.
2. Introduce a number of variables that are treated like binary bits, thereby allowing me to represent four levels with two variables, eight with three, and so on.

In either case, however, I do not understand how to then proceed with the analysis. How do I fit a linear model to an experiment containing variables encoded in that way?

There is, of course, software, that could do that part for me, but I am looking for a conceptual understanding.